# OData with a plain SQL (odbc) data source

Tags: sql, .net, oracle, odata

I have an oracle data source that i would like to expose using odata.

The reason i need to use odata is that there are many parameters and it is hard to write a query for each combination.

How can i connect my oracle database to odata to achieve this given that the database is version 10.2g which as i have read does not support Entity framework.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One of the solutions is using NHibernate, and here is a sample: http://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/WebApi/OData/v4/NHibernateQueryableSample/.